# How can I prevent implicit conversion of Octal/Hex/binary to Int in PyYAML?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

In the YAML file, I am expecting users to enter only Decimal integer values.

There are other objects in the YAML file as well. But, integer values will be specified without quotes. So, I am concerned only about the integer inputs.

Sample YAML file:

```
DecimalsList:
- 34
- 0432   # PyYAML converts 0432 to 287 by interpreting this as octal.
```

I am reading this YAML file in my python script using yamlordereddictloader

```
with open(yaml_file_path, 'r') as stream:
    yaml_object = yaml.load(stream,
                       Loader=yamlordereddictloader.Loader)
```

This will break my application logic as it does not match the value entered in YAML file.

I want to throw an error if anything other than decimal is entered in this list.

How can I achieve this ?

Is there a way to stop this implicit conversion for integers by PyYAML ?

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way to do this, but one way is to preprocess your yaml file and remove any leading zeroes with regex:

```
import re

with open(yaml_file_path, 'r') as stream:
    stream = re.sub(r'\b0(\d+)\b', r'\1', stream.read())
    yaml_object = yaml.load(stream,
                       Loader=yamlordereddictloader.Loader)
```

Comment: Thanks @jdaz, I am considering this option. 
There are other entries like strings in the YAML file which have no restriction on content. So, I want to use regex as last option to not have unintended match with regex.

If there is any way to do this through PyYaml to explicitly handle integers, that would be more helpful and safe.

I updated my question to my question to specify there are other entries in YAML file as well.

Comment: Will the integers always be on their own line?

Comment: No. Users can add as many integers as possible, but there will be one integer per line.

Comment: So...is that a yes? If there is one integer per line, you can modify the regex and see if that works for you: `\- \b0(\d+)\b\s+`

Comment: Thank you @Jdaz. I switched to ruamel library instead of pyYaml and there is an option to do not do implicit octal conversion inbuilt in this library.